# Cell autoreleased and "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Probably my code crashes in the following method, since the getData() is called only once - at the end of this method.

Moreover the didSelectRowAtIndexPath code is the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES];

    // Set 
    [[GlobalObject obj] setData:[(CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath] getData]];
}
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception *'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CustomCell getData]: **unrecognized selector sent to instance***.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        ...
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        // Create a button table view cell
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {           
            cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"] autorelease];
        }

         [cell setButton:[ ...];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

As shown above the cell is autoreleased and probably this is the reason the app crashed. Cell went to the autorelease pool and then getData sent to an unrecognized selector. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath] is obviously not returning an object of type CustomCell rarely. Not sure why. I see that you do deselect right before, are you doing any thing in deselect where you are deleting a row or some thing. Can you move the deselect to below this line.

Comment: @Srikanth: If the returned object is of a different type, wouldn't the error message look different?

Comment: Please post the header of your getData method in CustomCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CustomCell does noth have a method called getData.
Avoid inlining, write the statements one after another. This helps in debugging. You easily can then set a breakpoint.

Comment: I think if the returned object is not a CustomCell, you would not get this error message (which claims it tried to talk to a CustomCell).

Comment: @AlexWien how can I avoid inlining?

Comment: ok, updated my answer, but it should be not o diffcult to check whether ir not that getData() exists

Comment: CustomCell has a method called getData

Comment: @cateof by writing CustomCell *customCell = [tableView ...    then assign customCell to global obj

Comment: probably getData has one parameter? please post the method header,